# animateWithDuration doing animation based on completely unrelated line of code

Tags: ios, animation, uigesturerecognizer

Today animateWithDuration was acting really stupid and I don't know why really. I checked all the things, all the brackets and everything was perfect, but it was always presenting the line of code i didn't specify as an animation.

Ok, so here's the point. I have a longPressGestureRecognizer. It's on some UIImageView, which is being dragged, after the longPress begins. When it ends in some special zone I want to start the animation, taking the UIImageView to some other place and finish it. Here's my code:

```
if ([(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    CGPoint dropPoint = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y-5);
    for (UIView * placeForCharacter in delegate.subviews) {
        if ([placeForCharacter isKindOfClass:[PlaceForCharacterCircle class]]) {
            PlaceForCharacterCircle * newPlaceForCharacter = (PlaceForCharacterCircle *) placeForCharacter;
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(newPlaceForCharacter.dropZone, dropPoint)) {
                    UIViewAnimationOptions options = 0;
                    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
                        self.frame = CGRectMake(newPlaceForCharacter.frame.origin.x-8, newPlaceForCharacter.frame.origin.y-5, 40, 55);
                        self.alpha = 0.5;
                    } 
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        NSLog(@"animation completed");
                        self.alpha=1;
                        //code referring to the finalizing of moving, doesn't matter here
                        return;
                    }];
            } else {
                if (CGRectContainsPoint(newPlaceForCharacter.dropZone, dropPoint)) {
                    //code referring to the moving to the other place in case the UIImageView was dropped on another zone that is full already, doesn't matter here
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        //code referring to the comeback of a UIImageView in case it was dropped somewhere else, doesn't matter here
        //These two are the lines that get executed when the animation starts
        //THEY BEGIN
        translatedPoint = CGPointMake(initialX, initialY);
        [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];
        //THEY END
        return;
}
```

The case is that for some strange reason the two lines of code above get animated instead of the REAL animation, that was specified. I double-checked it by putting the comments on these lines of code - in this case the animation works just fine.

Could someone please clear this out for me, why does this happen? It seems to be a really strange behaviour.

Comment: which 2 lines do you mean???
In principal, the animation should be performed at the following 2 lines:
self.frame = CGRectMake(newPlaceForCharacter.frame.origin.x-8, newPlaceForCharacter.frame.origin.y-5, 40, 55);
                        self.alpha = 0.5;

Comment: I meant these two:
translatedPoint = CGPointMake(initialX, initialY);
[[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

Comment: I know what should be happening, but it doesn't and that is strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the `return;` from the completion block (where it's not doing anything) to after the animation is setup it should work.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
    self.frame = CGRectMake(newPlaceForCharacter.frame.origin.x-8, newPlaceForCharacter.frame.origin.y-5, 40, 55);
    self.alpha = 0.5;
}
completion:^{
    NSLog(@"animation completed");
    self.alpha=1;
    //code referring to the finalizing of moving, doesn't matter here
}];
return;
```

Comment: Well, that worked although I still can't get the point, why this return matters so much? Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Your code wasn't returning before it fell through to those last two lines and since the property center is animatable, you were seeing that.  By moving the return outside of the completion block your method call ended where you expected execution to end in the case of state =  ended.